# How to embed javascript confirmation box in Slim href?

Tags: javascript, slim-lang

I want the following action

```
a href= url(:event, :destroy, event: allocation.id, company_id: company.id) title="Delete This Event" ==t 'actions.delete'
```

to be done only after I agree to it on a confirmation box.  I want to embed in this href the javascript code:

```
'javascript:onClick=window.confirm("Are you SURE you want to Delete this Event?")'
```

I am using Slim.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using rails with jquery-ujs enabled, simply like this

`= link_to t('actions.delete'), url, confirm: 'Are you SURE you want to Delete this Event?'`